# How to force a WCF data service to refresh entities?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, service, refresh, entities

I'm using a WCF data Service to access a MSSQL database. If the client requests data (e.g. from the table "Projects") i build my cache like this:

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
foreach (var project in this.Entities.Project)
{
   collection.Add(project);
}

return collection;
```

If I want to refresh the list I just call

```
collection.Clear();
```

and call the above method again. If I edit a project and refresh the list as described above it works fine, but if i change the data on one client instance and refresh the list on another one the service doesn't load the changed project.

How can I force the DataService to re- load a whole entity (e.g. "Projects") even if from the service's point of view nothing has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

> ```
> public partial class Entities
> {
>     public void RefreshProject(Project pr)
>     {
>         this.Detach(pr);
>         pr = this.Project.Where(p => p.Id == pr.Id).Single();
>     }
> }
> ```

Usage:

> entities.RefreshProject(project);

Comment: I'm done with the project, I solved the problem some other way. Nevertheless this might be a working solution to the problem, so I will accept your answer.